# How to fix the "Access to the Path Denied" issue on C# Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, access-denied

I have made a program to modify a file, it works well when I run it regularly:

```
string modifiedFile = tmpPath + "\\Ext\\out.dat";
    FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite(modifiedFile);
    byte[] newData = new byte[2];
    newData[0] = 0x4B;
    newData[1] = 0x4B;
    writeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    writeStream.Write(newData, 0, newData.Length);
    writeStream.Close();
```

But if I run it from the Email client, which has an email with the attached file, when I click on the attached file (the format has associated to the program), the program runs but throws an error:

**Access to the path 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Ext\out.dat' is denied**

I checked the folder "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\Ext" and the out.dat file is there. What should I do to resolve this? It seems the system doesn't allow me to modify the file?

Comment: What permissions do you have on the file?

Comment: a) use System.IO.Path, thats what its there for b) sysinternals procmon is v useful for diagnosing file access issues c) I assume you dont have permission to write there

Comment: Check the `FileAttributes` by `File.GetAttributes(modifiedFile);` and make sure `ReadOnly` is not set.

Comment: @Loathing yes, it is ReadOnly! I have setAttributes to 0, solved. Thanks!